# When i enter data in the fields of my form and once i click submit the data is not printing in browser and also in server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Iam a Beginner to angular and nodejs technologies.I want to print the data which i gave in my template's register form but its not printing.instead if i took a dummy html form is printing once we press the submit button.my code is below.

```
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();  
app.use(express.static('public'));  
app.get('/register.html', function (req, res) {  
res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "register.html" );  
})  
app.get('/process_get', function (req, res) {  
// Prepare output in JSON format  
response = {  
    first_name:req.query.first_name,  
    last_name:req.query.last_name,  
    user_name:req.query.user_name,  
    password:req.query.password  
};  
console.log(response);  
res.end(JSON.stringify(response));  
})  
var server = app.listen(27017, function () {  
var host = server.address().address  
var port = server.address().port  
console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining `response` (`var response` instead)

```
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();  
app.use(express.static('public'));  
app.get('/register.html', function (req, res) {  
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "register.html" );  
});  
app.get('/process_get', function (req, res) {  
// Prepare output in JSON format  
   var response = {  
    first_name:req.query.first_name,  
    last_name:req.query.last_name,  
    user_name:req.query.user_name,  
    password:req.query.password  
   };  
   console.log(response);  
   res.end(JSON.stringify(response));  
});  
var server = app.listen(27017, function () {  
   var host = server.address().address;  
   var port = server.address().port;
   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port) ; 
});
```

---

**EDIT** : try with `res.send(JSON.stringify(response));` 
instead of `res.end(JSON.stringify(response));`

Comment: @user5945554 , I think the problem was using res.end() instead of res.send()